# Hibernate + SQLite не могут создать таблицу

Tags: java, sqlite, hibernate, netbeans

В моем проекте необходима база данных SQLite, с которой я буду работать через Hibernate. Работаю в Net Beans, ОС Ubuntu 17.10.

Вот мой тестовый мини-проект

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:stuff.db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">com.enigmabridge.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="stuff/Stuff.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Класс Stuff:

```
package stuff;

public class Stuff {
    private Integer id;
    private String stuff;

    public Stuff() {
    }

    public Stuff(String stuff) {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStuff() {
        return stuff;
    }

    public void setStuff(String stuff) {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stuff{" + "id=" + id + ", stuff=" + stuff + '}';
    }

}
```

Файл маппинга класса

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="stuff.Stuff" table="stuff">
      <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
          <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>
      <property name="stuff" type="string" column="stuff"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

И основная программа для тестов

```
package stuff;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(new Stuff("blah blah"));

        //Query q = session.createQuery("select from Stuff");
        //List<Stuff> l = q.list();
        //for (Stuff s:l)System.out.println(s);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

База данных создавалась через вкладку Службы в NetBeans. Имя базы -  stuff.db.

Используется Hibernate 4.3 (JPA 2.1)

Диалект SQLite для Hibernate 4 взят [отсюда](https://github.com/EnigmaBridge/hibernate4-sqlite-dialect).

База данных создается в домашней папке учетной записи убунты, Сессия проходит нормально, но почему-то в БД не создаются таблицы.

Comment: Пароля в конфиге  для доступа к бд нет

Comment: В SQLite вроде как нет пользователей, нет?

Comment: У тебя нет параметров для доступа к бд

Comment: В итоге это проблема в настройке БД в NetBeans или в настройке Hibernate?

Comment: настройки hibernate, что вы имеете в виду про проблему в NetBeans?

Comment: `<property name="connection.username"></property>
 <property name="connection.password"></property>` эти строчки не помогли

Comment: а вы сам пароль установили?

Comment: нет, логин и пароль оставил пустыми

Comment: Ну ясно тогда))